# Consume \r (^M) when reading with Python csv module

Tags: python, csv

Is there a way to get the python csv module to read a DOS file and filter out the \r (^M) characters in the new lines?

I've tried this:

```
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
   reader= csv.DictReader(csvfile)
   for row in header:
      for key in row.keys:
        print(f'{key} : {row[key]}')
```

This produces output on stdout with spurious ^M characters at the end of each line.

I'd prefer to skip running `dos2unix` on the file before processing it.  Is there a way to get csv to do the right thing when reading. (There is a lot written about writing the file without ^M but I don't see any on reading.)

Comment: `.strip()` the offending words.

Comment: So there is no way for the reader to do that automatically?

Comment: You can pass a `newline="\n\r"` option to `open`. It's `open` that controls the newlines, not the reader.